# If a player character transforms into a lich, does the DM control them?

Tags: dnd-5e, undead

I watched a video on how to become a lich and it said “when the beneficiary drinks the potion, he or she instantly transforms into a lich under the Dungeon Master’s control...”.

Does this mean that if I transform my character into a lich, the DM will control them?

Comment: related: [Can a PC be a lich?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/109138)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are no official rules for a player character becoming a lich. Also, no sources explicitly say that a PC that does become a lich falls under the DM's control.

In the absence of rules, you will have to hash this out with your DM.